# How can I make a playlist of singles

Tags: itunes

Over the years (!), I have collected a bunch of weekly freebies, plus I have bought a few singles. Is there any way that I can have a playlist made up of albums with just one track?

I just tried dragging everything over, but created a problem where iTunes continually crashed.

There has to be an easy way to do this. I can't believe it isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

If you tagged them correctly using the "Total Tracks" tag, then they should all be "Track 1 of 1".

Another option might be something along the lines of "Album contains 'Single of the Week'", but that does not cover any single tracks you bought.

Other than that there is no way to do it except manually.